# pandas dataframe aggregate calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe containing sports matches:

```
Winner      Loser          
A           B
B           A 
A           C
```

i want to have win-loss statistics for each player (i.e. A, B, and C). so for A the result should be 2-1. for B it should be 1-1 and for C it should be 0-1.

i know how to calculate this via iterating line-by-line over the dataframe with:

```
for index, match in df.iterrows():
    //code for calculating win-loss here
```

but I am sure that there is a more pythonic/pandas-ish way to do this? any hints on this are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `groupby` method with the `size` aggregate to do this

for example

```
print df.groupby('Loser').size()
```

Would yield a dataframe with the counts of number of losses.

```
Loser
A         1
B         1
C         1
dtype: int64
```

You can then combine these into the score counts as follows (using the [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method to set a default value if a team has no wins or losses)

```
wins = df.groupby('Winner').size()
losses = df.groupby('Loser').size()

scores = pd.DataFrame({'Wins' : wins, 'Losses' : losses}).fillna(0)
```

Yielding the final score counts as

```
   Losses  Wins
A       1     2
B       1     1
C       1     0
```

Comment: thanks. perfect solution. now i just want to beautify it by changing wins-losses columns.

Comment: to answer my question in above comment. this worked: `scores = scores.reindex_axis(['wins','losses'], axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

On way of doing it:

```
win = df.groupby('Winner').count()
los = df.groupby('Loser').count()
score = pd.DataFrame([win.Loser, los.Winner])
score
```

gives:

```
        A   B   C
Loser   2   1   0
Winner  1   1   1
```

and:

```
score.T
```

shows it transposed:

```
    Loser   Winner
A   2       1
B   1       1
C   0       1
```

This is the dataframe used above:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Winner': list('ABA'), 
                   'Loser': list('BAC')})  

df

  Loser  Winner
0 B      A
1 A      B
2 C      A
```

All in one line:

```
pd.DataFrame([df.groupby('Winner').count().Loser, 
              df.groupby('Loser').count().Winner]).fillna(0).T
```

results in:

```
    Loser   Winner
A   2       1
B   1       1
C   0       1
```

Comment: hm. the code seems to get stuck at "los = df.groupby('Loser').count()" ?

Answer (score 0):

What format do you want your results in?

A simple manner to count wins and losses would be to use collections.Counter:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df=pd.DataFrame([['A','B'],['B','C'],['A','C']], columns=['winner','loser'])

win_counts = Counter(df['winner'])
```

win_counts is a dictionary like the one below:

```
Counter({'A': 2, 'B': 1})
```

Still, I prefer Simon Gibbons answer above as it does not require additional modules.