# Pandas Dataframe Aggregate Object Type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, aggregate

**GOAL**

- I have a pandas dataframe with float and object types.
- I want to group the dataframe by the 'name' column
  `groupped = df.groupby(["name"])`
- Than aggregate all the other columns.
- There are columns with float values that I sum together
- But I also have 'Object types' and the goal would be to just keep 1 object type ex.: the 1st one. They are the same. So I am trying to use min but it doesn't works but I can not find any other function for it that works with object types.

```
aggregated = groupped.agg({ 
         'name' : ['min'],
         'id' : ['min'],
         'date' : ['min'],
         'number_one' : ['sum'],
         'type' : ['min'],
         'number_two' : ['sum'],
})
```

**ERROR**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-3594b7bd0c31> in <module>
      9          'number_one' : ['sum'],
     10          'type' : ['min'],
---> 11          'number_two' : ['sum'],
     12 })
     13 
...
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

**Already Tried**

- [pandas dataframe aggregate calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235591/pandas-dataframe-aggregate-calculation)
- [Filtering Pandas Dataframe Aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404492/filtering-pandas-dataframe-aggregate)
- [Aggregating in panda dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44984365/aggregating-in-panda-dataframe)
- [Pandas - DataFrame aggregate behaving oddly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892806/pandas-dataframe-aggregate-behaving-oddly)
- [Pandas Dataframe aggregating Statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62693225/pandas-dataframe-aggregating-statistics)
- [python pandas dataframe aggregate groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410867/python-pandas-dataframe-aggregate-groupby)
- [Conditionally Aggregating Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448147/conditionally-aggregating-pandas-dataframe)
- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for object columns:

```
aggregated = groupped.agg({ 
         'name' : ['first'],
         'id' : ['first'],
         'date' : ['first'],
         'number_one' : ['sum'],
         'type' : ['first'],
         'number_two' : ['sum'],
})
```

If want avoid `MultiIndex` remove `[]`:

```
aggregated = groupped.agg({ 
         'name' : 'first',
         'id' : 'first',
         'date' : 'first',
         'number_one' : 'sum',
         'type' : 'first',
         'number_two' : 'sum',
})
```

More general solution is for numeric columns aggregate `sum` and for another columns get first value in lambda function:

```
f = lambda x: x.sum() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else x.iat[0]
aggregated = groupped.agg(f)
```

Comment: Perfect in 30 sec. Thank you.